# Color mapping not displaying in viewport display

Tags: physics

Good day,

currently making an explosion in blender and i need to enable color mapping in order to display the smoke. But i dont see them in the viewport display setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Color Mapping* was recently renamed to *Grid Display*. In your screenshot you'll find it just at the bottom border of your drawn frame.

Comment: thank you so much